# Call view function with empty request object

Tags: python, django

I am trying to call a view function to test something in my application like so:

```
>>> from ingest.views import search_site
>>> request={'search_string':'billy','search_type':'title'}
>>> search_site(request)
```

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'GET'

How do I create an empty request objcect, such as the above that I can test a view function with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django provides testing tools for exactly this case.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/

Answer (score 1):

As the above answer states, you can use django's [testing tools](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/). Here is how I used it to simulate the client:

```
from django.test import Client
import json
from ingest.views import search_site
c = Client()
response = c.get('/search_site/?search_string=billy&search_type=title')
data = json.loads(response.content)

len(data)
26
```